# wxPython on Mac OS X: creating a wx.Frame without stealing focus

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, pyobjc

I managed to get it working on Win32 (inheriting from wx.MiniFrame does the trick), on wxGTK (wx.PopupWindow) but whatever I try, when I create a frame on wxMac, my main window loses focus and the new frame gets it.

wxMac does not seem to have a way to interact with the native platform (something like GetHandle() on Win32 and GetGTKWidget() on wxGTK), so I can't hack around it this way.

I managed to get this working in another situation, by creating the frame at startup and moving it outside of the display area, then moving it in a visible position when needed. But right now this would be cumbersome because I don't know in advance how many frames I will need.

So, any simpler way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get native handle to window in Mac you can do

```
frame.MacGetTopLevelWindowRef()
```

and may be you can use [pyobjc](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/) to interact with windows natively, but why don't you set focus on the window you want to after opening mini-frame?

Comment: Because it doesn't work. I've tried many things based on SetFocus() at different moments and none actually give the focus back to the main frame.

Comment: Okay, this is the function I was looking for. Now trying to get some actual documentation about Carbon and use ctypes...